# Seeing an image on my camera that's not in the project outliner

Tags: camera, grease-pencil

There's an image that I can't delete that shows up on my camera object. It disappears only when I turn off my camera. It also disappears when I turn off the overlay. (Please note that my stroke object is also off in the outliner).

[image: camera off]

I've tried

- looking for this image but I've definitely deleted it. There is nothing in the outliner for this image.
- removing this camera and replacing with another one (but I'm having trouble setting the new one where the old one was).

How do I remove this image?

Comment: Did you check for annotation layers (property panel)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Carlo, what specifically do you mean about the property panel? I have it opened. It looks like if I uncheck viewport- the image disappears (but comes back when I check it)

Comment: can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set a [camera background image](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html#background-images). This image is used as an overlay in the background or in front of all objects when you look through the camera in the viewport.

Viewport overlays must be enabled and the camera must be visible in the viewport to see the image.

This option is very useful when you need an image for reference along with an exact angle of view and a given focal length as specified by the camera. The [F-Spy addon](https://fspy.io/) uses this option.

You can add more than one image. To turn it off either disable the whole feature by unchecking the *Background Images* checkbox (1). Or disable an individual background image by clicking the monitor icon (2). Or use the X button...

[image: camera background image option]